# Trying to redirect with additional query containing the URI filetype within the query param

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i am trying to figure out how to translate

```
/mainpage.html -> /index.php?page=_.mainpage
/mainpage.html?paramX=some.html -> /index.php?page=_.mainpage&paramX=some.html
/mainpage/subpage.html -> /index.php?page=mainpage.subpage
/mainpage/subpage.html?paramY=some.html -> /index.php?page=mainpage.subpage&paramY=some.html
```

and i am using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=_.$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1.$2 [QSA,L]
```

my problem is, as long as no query params are not given, it all works - any idea?

Edit:
param is just a placeholder of a bunch of multiple params.

Edit 2:
it actually worked - i had php code triggered on another GET param in PHP, redirecting to '/', which made it appear broken.

Edit 3:
added 2 more resolving examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=_.$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1.$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks :) but param was just an example of a bunch of query params - i try to adopt it

Comment: So do you want if QUERY_STRING contains `.html` then do this rewrite?

Comment: thanks for the effort - i had redirect on a param, which i used in another request set --- it actually worked

Comment: your code didn't actually work for me, when i called `/mainpage.html` and `/mainpage/subpage.html` - sorry

Comment: It won't work because you wrote something else in question and trying something else. You have to enter `domain.com/mainpage.html?param=some.html` to test it NOT `/mainpage.html` Also make sure to test these rules independently by taking out any other rule from this .htaccess

Comment: Sorry for causing missunderstandings. I clearified the exmaple a bit more. Anyway - so far, what I have, works at least now.